# HeatMap with custom colors for each cell

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

i'm trying to generate a heatmap with custom colors for each cell based on the coordinates/ x and y axis points.

[image: sample heatmap]

Now in the fiddle i did this but it is hardcoded, how to make it dynamic, please refer this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/253/), wanted to make this part dynamic for all colors. TIA

```
            {x:0,y:0, value:100,color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:1, value:10, color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:2, value:20, color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:3, value:30, color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:4, value:40, color:'red'},
            {x:0,y:0, value:50, color:'red'},
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? What do you need? Just being able to change it once after setting it?

Comment: Here in manually passing X,Y and Value... I'm getting the same from DB in the form of array object. So how to pass those values to the chart.plz refer the fiddle ull understand what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: Sounds like an issue of just convering the DB data into the correct format to pass the data into the Highcharts options.

Comment: No. i'm getting Category, Series and Measure values from DB, now i've to give color to those cells and that should be dynamic(refers to even when number of category/series change the color structure of the plot should not change, it should adjust values of Cateory and Series) , in fiddle i've hard coded the coordinate i need to make that dynamic [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/254/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use load event and then manipulate colors (based on logic).

```
 events:{
            load:function() {
                var points = this.series[0].data,
                    lenY = this.yAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1,
                    lenX = this.xAxis[0].tickPositions.length - 1,
                    x = lenX,
                    tmpX = 0,
                    y = 0,
                    j = 0;

                $.each(points, function(i, p){

                    if(p.x == 0 || p.y == 0) {
                        p.update({
                            color: 'red'
                        },false);
                    } else if(p.x > 0 && p.y > 0 && (p.y == x  || (p.y + 1) == x)) {
                        p.update({
                            color: 'green'
                        },false);

                        if(p.y == x)
                            x--;

                    } else if(p.x > 1 && p.y > 0 && p.y > x) {
                        p.update({
                            color: 'orange'
                        },false);
                    } else if(p.x > 0 && p.y > 0 && x > 2) {
                         p.update({
                            color: 'yellow'
                        },false);
                    }

                });

                this.isDirty = true;
                this.redraw();
            }
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4aqhB/260/

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, can we make the same thing for  i.e. {x:0,y:0} points/coordinates, color structure for each cell is same as you did. Thanks again made my day....

Comment: All depends on conditions, I prepare a example bad on your mockup.